# Returning results from controller (Laravel) but doesn't affected by jquery codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I did live search by using ajax and have other jquery customizations (Tilt.js etc..) for my card component.
I get search results successfully but it doesn't have whole js customizations .

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#location , #sector').on('change',function(){
         var location = $('#location').val();
         var sector = $('#sector').val();
         
        $.ajax({
            url:'search',
            type:'GET',
            data:{
                'location':location,
                'sector':sector,
            },
            success:function(data){
                $('#content').html(data);
            }
        })
    }) });
```

Component that returns from Controller

```
$output ='';

    foreach($data as $post){
        $output .='
        <div class="card mb-4" id="card" data-tilt data-tilt-max="5" data-tilt-glare data-tilt-max-glare="0.2">
        <div class="card-body">
     
         
        <div class="card my-2 rounded shadow item" role="button" id="'.$post->id.'"    >
             <div class="row no-gutters">
                 <div class="col-sm-2 pt-3 pl-2">
                 <img src="'.$post->image.'" class="img-fluid resim" alt="...">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <h4 style="font-weight: bolder;">'. $post->company_name.'</h4>
                     <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold;">'. $post->job_title.'</h5>
                     <p class="card-text">'. $post->description.'.</p>
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-sm"><div class="rounded-pill text-white text-center py-2 sector " style="background-color: #003777;"> '.$post->sector.'</div></div>
                         <div class="col-sm"><div class="rounded-pill text-white text-center py-2 location " style="background-color: #003777;"> '.$post->location.'</div></div>
                         <div class="col-sm"><div class="rounded-pill text-white text-center py-2  " style="background-color: #003777;"> Apply Now!</div></div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        
     </div>
        ';
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the ajax call ? Since your DOM isn't on the page at the first load, automated jQuery init aren't call

Comment: For tilt, somesing like `$('.selector').tilt();`

Comment: So what you are asking is, why isnt js running on dom elements returned after page load?

Comment: @MichaelMano Exactly! All card components have jquery affects at the beginning but when i filter by changing select value i get cards but non-effect ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to javascript only loads once the document has finished loading, It then scans all of your dom elements for the elements and adds the listeners, If you are loading dom elements in after this has happened they will not have the event listeners. To get around this there are a few ways but one of the easiest is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.js-card',function(){
        // This body click function will only trigger if the element has the class js-card.
    });
});
```

Another way is to add the onclick to the elements you are loading in `<button onClick="yourGlobalFunction">`